# Android app that allows me to use my phone as a USB microphone

Tags: gratis, android, windows-7

Is there a free Android app that lets me use the microphone in my phone as a USB microphone I can connect to my computer.

It should:

- be free
- only act as a microphone (don't need images or anything else)
- work via USB (not wifi or bluetooth)
- be detected by my computer just like a normal USB microphone would
- **not require any extra client software to be installed on my computer**

Comment: Your answer can be found in this question thread.  
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8492/using-droid-as-a-computer-microphone-via-usb

Comment: @Jordy, I was going to recommend that, but none of those fit the requirements.

Comment: @Jordy thanks but none of them do what I want :( however it now seems impossible reading some of those answers :(!